# Can't click on an element using webdriver in python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I need help with click on an element using selenium webdriver in python.

Here is the html code for reference:
I am trying to click on an element named "SYSTEM"

```
<body>
<div id="toparea">
<div id="logo" style="top: 10px; z-index: 3">
<div id="welcome">
<div id="topmenu1">
<ul>
<li id="home" class="selected" style="right: 636px">
<li id="incidents" style="right: 530px">
<li id="case" style="right: 424px">
<li id="capture" style="right: 318px">
<li id="policies" style="right: 212px">
<li id="classify" style="right: 106px">
<li id="system" style="right: 0px">
<a onclick="location.href='/imanager/ReShowMenuBar.do?selectedtab=system'" title="SYSTEM" target="mainFrame" href="/devicemgr/ReSystemAdministration.do">SYSTEM</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

I tried using:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='system']/a")
```

tried finding the element using link_text, id but all in vain.

I am also not sure if my xpath is correct, I am trying to learn.

Answer (score 4):

Find it *by link text*:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("SYSTEM")
```

You may need to [*wait for the element to be clickable*](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#waits) also:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
system = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "SYSTEM")))
system.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways that you can located an element using selenium and python. In your case, you could potentially use **find_element_by_css_selector** or **find_element_by_xpath**, your HTML code indentation is a bit hard to read, so I am assuming **body** encloses everthing and **ul** all **li** below it.
I am using Chrome as my example, if you are using Firefox, it is natively supported by Selenium, which means you do not need to provide a Firefox path as I did for Chrome below.

```
chrome = webdriver.Chrome('PathToChromeDriver.exe')
element = chrome.find_element_by_xpath("//body//ul//li[@id='system']")
```

Or alternatively, you can find your element by asking for the 7th li element under ui, this time, I am using Firefox in my example.

```
firefox = webdriver.Firefox()
element = firefox.find_element_by_xpath("//body//ul//li[7]")
```

My personal favorite way to locate an element is via css selector:

```
firefox = webdriver.Firefox()
element = firefox.find_element_by_css_selector("li[id='system']")
```

In case you have two elements that share the same IDs, e.g. id = 'system', you can use css selector to fine select your element, for example:

```
firefox = webdriver.Firefox()
element = firefox.find_element_by_css_selector("li[id='system'][style='right: 0px']")
```

Basically, you can append as many attributes as you need to uniquely locate an element:

```
firefox = webdriver.Firefox()
element = firefox.find_element_by_css_selector("li[id='system'][style='right: 0px'][attribute3 = 'value'][attribute4 = 'value']")
```

Below are two links you may find helpful:
http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox();

driver.findElement(By.id("SYSTEM")).click();
```